# set php radio button checked by default

Tags: php, html, forms, wordpress, button

I have two radio buttons in my program but when i run it none of them is checked, I want one of them to be checked by default,
how can i achieve this ?

```
<li><input type="radio" name="r1" value="o" onClick="submit();" <?php echo ($_SESSION['r1'] == "o") ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />On</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="r1" value="p" onClick="submit();" <?php echo ($_SESSION['r1'] == "p") ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />Off</li>
```

I want the 'On' button to be checked when i open the page for the first time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<li><input type="radio" name="r1" value="o" onClick="submit();" CHECKED/>On</li>
```

Answer (score 12):

Here you go:

```
<li><input type="radio" name="r1" value="o" onClick="submit();" <?php echo ($_SESSION['r1'] != "p") ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />On</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="r1" value="p" onClick="submit();" <?php echo ($_SESSION['r1'] == "p") ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />Off</li>
```

Comment: if i do this it always remain 'On' , i want it to be 'On' by default but when i select 'Off' , it goes off

Comment: well, than you have to check your original code. dump the `$_SESSION['r1']` and see what it says

Comment: <?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['r1'])){
    $_SESSION['r1']=$_POST['r1'];
 }
?>

Comment: see my edit, should be working now. When you first access the page, it's On. If you change it to off, it will remain Off.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
<li><input type="radio" name="r1" value="o" onClick="submit();" <?php echo (!$_SESSION['r1'] || $_SESSION['r1'] == "o") ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />On</li
```

Comment: yeah, that's what i've said 19 seconds ago.

Comment: the statement `!$_SESSION['r1']` checks it the value is set at all. if not, checked will be set.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in order for the On button to checked, the `$_SESSION['r1']` must be equal to "o". Have you checked the value of `$_SESSION['r1']`?

Comment: then it always remain 'On', i want it to be 'on' by default but when i 'select 'off' it goes 'off'

<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['r1'])){
    $_SESSION['r1']=$_POST['r1'];
 }
?>

Comment: this doesn't answer the question