# How to add POST method

Tags: php, html, sql, post

**EDIT:**

[image]

**CODE:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
                  <input type = "submit" name="sql_update" value="SQL Update">
                  <?php $admin_checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" name="admin_status">';?>
                      </form>

$getusers = "SELECT id, username, firstname, lastname, admin FROM registered_users";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $getusers);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br>". $row["id"]. " &nbsp; - &nbsp;  " . $row["username"]. "  &nbsp; - &nbsp;  " . $row["firstname"]. " &nbsp; - &nbsp;  " .$row["lastname"]. "  &nbsp; - &nbsp;  " .$row["admin"]. "  &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;  " .$admin_checkbox. "<br>";
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['sql_update'])) {
  if (empty($_POST["admin_status"])){
    echo ("Ni obkljukano");
  }
```

How to connect  with $admin_checkbox that this code will work correctly.

```
if (empty($_POST["admin_status"])){
    echo ("Ni obkljukano");
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

Everything is working perfectly!

Now i also want to know how can i do a reverse effect. If user is already a admin. What do i have to type in elseif statement. I really feel bad for asking so many questions tho :/

```
if (isset($_POST['sql_update'])) {
  if (empty($_POST["admin_status"])){
    echo ("Ni izbranih elementov.");
  } 
  elseif(){

    $sql_admin_off = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE registered_users SET admin = 0 WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $_POST['admin_status']).") ");
    $sql_admin_off;
    echo("test");

  }
  else {

    $sql_admin_on = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE registered_users SET admin = 1 WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $_POST['admin_status']).") ");
    $sql_admin_on;
    echo("SQL uspešno zapisan!");

  }


    }
```

UPDATE #2

```
if (isset($_POST['sql_update'])) {
  if (empty($_POST["admin_status"])){
    echo ("Ni izbranih elementov.");
  } else {

    $sql_admin_on = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE registered_users SET admin = 1 WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $_POST['admin_status']).") ");
    $sql_admin_on;
    echo("SQL uspešno zapisan!");


    $sql_admin_off = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE registered_users SET admin = 0 WHERE id NOT IN (".implode(',', $_POST['admin_status']).") ");
    $sql_admin_off;
    echo("test");
  }

  }
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) page. For your question, is this what you mean: Once open it will lists all users + checkbox (admin rights). And once submitted it will give the user with checkbox checked an admin right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've successfully list all users with admin checkboxes:

**HTML Form**

When you list all the user with checkbox for each user, set the checkbox value to `userId`. Also use **field name array** to group all the checkboxes `name="adminId[]"`. Later on `$_POST['adminId']` will contain arrays of `ID's` in which the checkbox were **checked**.

Then, you can simply use SQL `in` operator to **update** 'admin_rights=true', if **ID** is listed in `$_POST['adminId']`. The [`Implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) will join array elements with a string(`,`).

```
<form action="..." method="post">
    <label>
       User ID1: 
       <!-- Admin Checkbox -->
       <input type="checkbox" name="adminId[]" value="id1" />
    </label><br>
    <label>
       User ID2: 
       <!-- Admin Checkbox -->
       <input type="checkbox" name="adminId[]" value="id2" />
    </label><br>
    <label>
       User ID3: 
       <!-- Admin Checkbox -->
       <input type="checkbox" name="adminId[]" value="id3" />
    </label><br>
    <input type="submit" id="edit" name="edit"/>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// If edit button pressed
if( isset($_POST['edit'])) )
{
    // If Admin checkbox were selected then add Admin Rights
    if (isset($_POST['adminId']){
       $sql = 'UPDATE `usertable` SET `admin_rights`= 'true' WHERE id IN ('.implode(',', $_POST['adminId']).')';
       mysqli_query($sql);
    }
}
?>
```

It seems like I misunderstood your problem, you are still having problem listing out users with checkbox (as a whole form).

Take a look at the **form** below:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type = "submit" name="sql_update" value="SQL Update">
           
<?php
   $getusers = "SELECT id, username, firstname, lastname, admin FROM registered_users";
   $result = mysqli_query($db, $getusers);

   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         if ($row['admin'] == 1){
              echo "<br>". $row['id']. " &nbsp; - &nbsp;  " . $row['username']. "  &nbsp; - &nbsp;  " . $row['firstname']. " &nbsp; - &nbsp;  " .$row['lastname']. "  &nbsp; - &nbsp;  " .$row['admin']. "  &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type='checkbox' name='admin_status[]' value='".$row['id']."' checked><br>";
         }
         else echo "<br>". $row['id']. " &nbsp; - &nbsp;  " . $row['username']. "  &nbsp; - &nbsp;  " . $row['firstname']. " &nbsp; - &nbsp;  " .$row['lastname']. "  &nbsp; - &nbsp;  " .$row['admin']. "  &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type='checkbox' name='admin_status[]' value='".$row['id']."'><br>";
       }
   }
?>
</form>
```

The code to check `$_POST` value:

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['sql_update'])) {
       if (empty($_POST["admin_status"])){
         echo ("Ni obkljukano");
       }
   }
?>
```

Further Update for **UPDATE #2**

```
if (isset($_POST['sql_update'])) {
  // All unchecked, set all admin to 0
    if (empty($_POST['admin_status'])){
        $sql_admin_off = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE user SET admin = 0");
    }
    else{
        $sql_admin_on = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE user SET admin = 1 WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $_POST['admin_status']).") ");
        $sql_admin_off = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE user SET admin = 0 WHERE id NOT IN (".implode(',', $_POST['admin_status']).") ");
    }
}
```

Comment: You might misunderstood my problem or maybe i just don't know what am i doing :P.  I Edited my post, might help u understand now.

Comment: Hello, sorry if I misunderstood your problem. So your problem is to echo the `checkbox` and make it work with `$_POST`? You should wrap the whole thing(listing all users) with one form. You do not have to put the form in php variable and then `echo` it everytime you list out a user. Simply echo a `<form>` tag before listing with a update button, and echo a closing `</form>` tag right after your while loop. You should also use **field array name** like `admin_status[]` for checkbox.

Comment: Can you give me an example ?  I'm trying to understand but like i said im really new  i want to learn as much as i can but its really hard without help

Comment: I've also added the value in checkbox, and set it to the user id. This way $_POST(admin_status) will return an array of id's with checkbox checked (admin status).

Comment: Thank you it's working. But now i have another problem.

Comment: $sql_admin = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE registered_users SET admin = 1 WHERE id =  ");    How to finish this code ?

Comment: I think you can try this: `mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE registered_users SET admin = 1 WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $_POST['admin_status']).") ");`

Comment: You are amazing, thank you so much. Now i have 2 more questions and then we can close this post :)  name='admin_status[]' value='".$row['id']."'  Can you explain what does [] does and how does value work with $row['id']

Comment: The other question is can you explain me how this works and when should be used.       
 IN (".implode(',', $_POST['admin_status']).")

Comment: Yes, whole code is working as it should. Yeah no problem, have a nice day at work.

Comment: I updated my post, i have one last problem :/

Comment: You shouldn't put `if and else` under `if (isset($_POST['sql_update']))` because `$_POST["admin_status"]` can actually be empty: when all users checkbox is not  checked, it will return empty, but you still need to run the query, to remove admin right. You can try to uncheck all checkbox and press update, it will echo `Ni izbranih elementov.` but won't update the admin right.

Comment: Well it works only partly because if i give admin to 1 user the other one lose admin status. Also if they both have admin status and i want to remove that status nothing happens.

Comment: Updated post for you to check updated code.

Comment: Like if both users have admin status = 1 and i try to check both checkboxes and press SQL Update button then nothing happens and if i for example check only checkbox for user id 2 the admin status changes only for user id 1 and it keeps user id 2 as an admin.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean, actually when you list out users,  you can decide whether to have it checked or not by default, this way users with admin status = 1 will have its checkbox automatically checked, so it will still have the admin right, unless you uncheck the checkbox. I will add it up later. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868806/set-php-radio-button-checked-by-default/8868814) first, it can help. Using row['admin'] and check if it's true or 1, then echo `checked` inside `<input>` tag.

Comment: Okay, i will probably wait for you because my brain really hurt right now :/ Have to stop for some time now. My problem is that im not learning language from start. I am trying to learn it just from building stuff and i know its wrong but learning hello world is really boring. Do you have any tips ? How did you learned programming ?

Comment: I know what you mean, but i don't have any ideas right now how to implement that into the <input>   I tried  ->  if ($row['admin'] == 1 { $checkbox_checked = "checked"}  and put $checkbox_checked into <input> but it doesn't work. I am probably missing the point here.

Comment: Hello, I've just edited the Form code,  `if (row['admin'] == 1) echo '<input ... checked> else '<input .. >`

Comment: Its working, but still... if both users are admin = 1 and if i uncheck both checkboxes it doesnt want to change the value of both users to 0. They both stay at 1.

Comment: I deleted that statement and its the same thats why i am still here haha

Comment: Okay, got it. I've just made an edit for your UPDATE#2. Sorry the SQL failed when no checkbox failed, it's an invalid SQL, so when no checkbox checked, under `if(empty($_POST[..]))`, you can set all admin to 0. What I did I simply echoed the SQL and turns out it's an invalid SQL, if you tried to copy paste it in phpMyAdmin `SQL`, it will failed and return error. So next time if your query fails, you can always echo the query and check if it works on PhpMyAdmin to  see if the SQL syntax is invalid.

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanations. You are an amazing guy!